# Invalid parameter when saving bitmap

Tags: c#, bitmap

When I run this code:

```
Bitmap img = new Bitmap(200, 200);
img.Dispose();
img.Save("somefilename.png", ImageFormat.Png);
```

I get an error saying that I have an invalid parameter at `img.Save`. I've searched about this and I do not know what is wrong.

PS: Sorry for my bad english.

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try reversing the order of your statements. You Dispose the object and then try to call the save method. Dispose releases all resources and makes the image unusable.

Read up on the Dispose method [here](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/fs2xkftw(v=vs.110).aspx)

```
Bitmap img = new Bitmap(200, 200);
img.Save("somefilename.png", ImageFormat.Png);
img.Dispose();
```

Answer (score 0):

I'm pretty sure `Dispose` release *all* resources for an image and you're not meant to try do anything with it after that point.

From the [documentation](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/8th8381z(v=vs.110).aspx):

> Call Dispose when you are finished using the Image. The Dispose method leaves the Image in an unusable state.